# How do I fix simplepie? failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, rss, atom-feed, simplepie

I am trying to pull in some posts from a remote wordpress site with simplepie. I have installed the library and put what I think is the right code at the top of the .php page.

Right now my it looks like:

```php
<?php
require_once('../autoloader.php');

$feed = new SimplePie();

$feed->set_feed_url('http://simplepie.org/blog/feed/');

$feed->enable_cache(true); 
$feed->set_cache_location('cache'); 
$feed->set_cache_duration(1800);

$feed->init();

$feed->handle_content_type();

?>    {doc type}
```

But when I load my page it tells me:

> Warning: require_once(../autoloader.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/27/9279927/html/LatestHOPE.php on line 2
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '../autoloader.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5_3/lib/php') in /home/content/27/9279927/html/LatestHOPE.php on line 2

What's up with that? Why is it telling me this? 
I have autoloader.php in my root directory.

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it in your *root directory*!?  That is a strange location.  However, if that is true, use

```
require_once('/autoloader.php');
```

Perhaps you mean in your home directory?  For that use

```
require_once('/home/<your username>/autoloader.php');
```

Comment: Yea, root, I put it there because it couldn't find it when I put it in the php folder with require_once('../php/autoloader.php'); 

Thanks so much!

Comment: I have started a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507